# probability of collision

Tags: probability-theory, hash, statistics

my data's range is from 1 to 9 and I have two subsets of integers from this range.
the hash function takes each of this subsets and calculate product of these three integers and maps this set to the result of this multiplication.I want to know the probability of collision by this hash function with this two subsets of integers that they are from 1 to 9 and the size of each subset equals 3.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: we have C(9,3) = 84 situations and the least multiplication that can occur is 1*2*3=6 and the greatest is 9*8*7=504.but I can't calculate the multiplication result for each situation and then see if two or more situations like 2*6*1=12 and 3*4*1=12 have the same result or not.I am looking for a better way.if you can give me some hint I'll be appreciated.

Comment: I do not see any easy and fast method by hand. However, you can probably write a program in your favorite programming language in several minutes to compute the result, which is more likely to be faster and correct.

Comment: I am going to brute-force this by using Python

Comment: Is something like {8,7,9} and {9,8,7} the same?

Comment: yes,because these are sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [a Python program](https://repl.it/@Apass_Jack/HashCollisioncs102385) that uses brute-force to compute the probability of hash collision of two randomly-chosen different 3-element subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$.

Here is the output of the program.

```
6 [(1, 2, 3)]
8 [(1, 2, 4)]
10 [(1, 2, 5)]
12 [(1, 2, 6), (1, 3, 4)]
14 [(1, 2, 7)]
16 [(1, 2, 8)]
18 [(1, 2, 9), (1, 3, 6)]
15 [(1, 3, 5)]
21 [(1, 3, 7)]
24 [(1, 3, 8), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 4)]
27 [(1, 3, 9)]
20 [(1, 4, 5)]
28 [(1, 4, 7)]
32 [(1, 4, 8)]
36 [(1, 4, 9), (2, 3, 6)]
30 [(1, 5, 6), (2, 3, 5)]
35 [(1, 5, 7)]
40 [(1, 5, 8), (2, 4, 5)]
45 [(1, 5, 9)]
42 [(1, 6, 7), (2, 3, 7)]
48 [(1, 6, 8), (2, 3, 8), (2, 4, 6)]
54 [(1, 6, 9), (2, 3, 9)]
56 [(1, 7, 8), (2, 4, 7)]
63 [(1, 7, 9)]
72 [(1, 8, 9), (2, 4, 9), (3, 4, 6)]
64 [(2, 4, 8)]
60 [(2, 5, 6), (3, 4, 5)]
70 [(2, 5, 7)]
80 [(2, 5, 8)]
90 [(2, 5, 9), (3, 5, 6)]
84 [(2, 6, 7), (3, 4, 7)]
96 [(2, 6, 8), (3, 4, 8)]
108 [(2, 6, 9), (3, 4, 9)]
112 [(2, 7, 8)]
126 [(2, 7, 9), (3, 6, 7)]
144 [(2, 8, 9), (3, 6, 8)]
105 [(3, 5, 7)]
120 [(3, 5, 8), (4, 5, 6)]
135 [(3, 5, 9)]
162 [(3, 6, 9)]
168 [(3, 7, 8), (4, 6, 7)]
189 [(3, 7, 9)]
216 [(3, 8, 9), (4, 6, 9)]
140 [(4, 5, 7)]
160 [(4, 5, 8)]
180 [(4, 5, 9)]
192 [(4, 6, 8)]
224 [(4, 7, 8)]
252 [(4, 7, 9)]
288 [(4, 8, 9)]
210 [(5, 6, 7)]
240 [(5, 6, 8)]
270 [(5, 6, 9)]
280 [(5, 7, 8)]
315 [(5, 7, 9)]
360 [(5, 8, 9)]
336 [(6, 7, 8)]
378 [(6, 7, 9)]
432 [(6, 8, 9)]
504 [(7, 8, 9)]
3-element subsets: 84
total pairs: 3486
duplicity:  27
probability: 0.00774526678141136
```

The last line of the above output shows the wanted probability is $\dfrac{27}{3486}\approx 0.0077$.

I do not see any mathematical technique that can lead to an easy and fast calculation by hand. If we are asked to compute that kind of probability for many-element subsets such as 10-elements subsets of $\{1,2,\cdots, 40\}$, we might be motivated to find a more efficient solution such as using integer factorization or some algorithms from the problem of subset sums, which may or may not be useful. Otherwise, a program that takes several minutes to write and less than a second to run is the perfect usage of our programming ability and our computers.

Answer (score 0):

I made [a program](https://pastebin.com/pNHuJwHk) to brute force this.

This means that a very close low bound of this would be $\frac{36}{441}$, so a not that big chance.

If you wanted to avoid overlaps, I suggest you either use a different algorithm or block out all the duplicates, because the chance of this overlapping is pretty high ($8\%$).

Comment: thanks for your help.but I wonder if there is a mathematically approach to do this or not?

Comment: @mohamadreza There probably is, but I don't know